# Google oauth without a browser

Tags: c#, google-api

Hi,

We have a 'client application' that performs some administration tasks, it looks at a user's google account, checks in what group the user in and determines the user's rights within the administration application. Now we want to use the Rest API of the administration application and do some periodic routines with it. As i understand, it should be another 'user application' that has credentials to some google account.

I don't understand how to implement a flow where the 'user application' would give its consent to 'client application' because the 'user application' cannot have a browser. Is such flow even possible?

P.S I'm using C#